# Ubuntu 16.10 Asus N550JA subwoofer not working

Tags: sound, alsa

I have a notebook Asus N550JA, and it has an external subwoofer, which does not work since Ubuntu 14.04.4 , strangely enough it works with Ubuntu 14.04.3, but after updates it does not work, seems to be something with alsa settings.

I want to make it work now in Ubuntu 16.10 . Can somebody help me with this problem ?

Here are some outputs:

```
    sudo lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 37
    Memory at f7e14000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 36
    Memory at f7e10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel


 sudo aplay -l
**** Lista PLAYBACK de dispozitive ****
placa 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], dispozitiv 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  subdispozitive: 1/1
  Subdispozitiv #0: subdevice #0
placa 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], dispozitiv 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  subdispozitive: 1/1
  Subdispozitiv #0: subdevice #0
placa 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], dispozitiv 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  subdispozitive: 1/1
  Subdispozitiv #0: subdevice #0
placa 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispozitiv 0: ALC668 Analog [ALC668 Analog]
  subdispozitive: 0/1
  Subdispozitiv #0: subdevice #0

amixer -c 0
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',2
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
```

Comment: What kind of subwoofer, how is it connected, and which devices are shown in System Settings > Sound > Output?

Comment: http://www.asus.com/websites/global/products/CjoMCNPscHzQ19hl/images/sound/subwoofer/subwoofer02.png

Comment: In Output i have some internal audio device(it does not say which one ), and mode:  Surround 2.1 enabled, but changing the subwoofer volume does not do anything, in testing i hear only for front right and left speakers , no sound from  subwoofer .